# Upgrading to swift 2 causes errors that i'm struggling to get around

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm upgrading a project from swift 1 to 2 and I'm trying to resolve all the issues that have popped up.

I still have some left that i'm struggling to get around.

I have this method which is throwing the errors as you can see. I know it has something to do with do/try/catch but i've been unable to get them to go away with any of my attempts.:

```
struct EventDao {

    // MARK: Functions

    /**
        Get all the upcoming events
    */
    static func getUpcoming(callback: (NSArray?, String?) -> Void) {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: Constants.makeUrl("/events"))!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("myezteamToken")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {  <-- // INVALID CONVERSION FROM THROWING FUNCTION OF TYPE '(_, _, _) THROWS -> VOID' TO NON-THROWING FUNCITON '(NSDATA?, NSURLRESPONSE?, NSERROR?) -> VOID'
                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    callback(nil, error.localizedDescription) <-- // TYPE OF EXPRESSION IS AMBIGUOUS WITHOUT MORE CONTEXT
                } else {
                    let newData: NSData = data
                    let upcomingEvents: NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(newData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSArray
                    callback(upcomingEvents, nil)
                }
            }


        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to unwrap your `error` property if it's not nil. Then, you need to wrap your JSON serialization code in do/try/catch. The error message you are getting is a red-herring. Once you wrap the JSON stuff in do/try/catch it will go away. You will also want to use `as?` when you typecast the result of `JSONObjectWithData` to `NSArray`. Try this:

```
static func getUpcoming(callback: (NSArray?, String?) -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "bob")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("myezteamToken")
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback(nil, error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            let newData: NSData = data!
            let upcomingEvents: NSArray?
            do {
                upcomingEvents = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(newData, 
                    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSArray
            } catch {
                upcomingEvents = nil
            }
            callback(upcomingEvents, nil)
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```